# Restrict access to "destroy" feature in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-2

Thanks in advance for your help! I have a site built in Ruby on Rails (2.3.15, 1.8.7) that lets people create itineraries to different locations and with different activities at each location. The site has a way of ensuring that the current user can only delete the itineraries associated with his account. The code in itineraries_controller.rb to do this looks something like this:

```
def destroy
  @itinerary = Itinerary.find(params[:id])
  if @itinerary.user_id == current_user.id

    @itinerary.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to('/home') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

This system works well. I want to do the same thing for the activities, however. In the activities_controller, I want to ensure that the current user can only delete the activities associated with his account.

Currently, here are my four models (with unnecessary stuff stripped out):

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :itineraries
end
```

Itinerary.rb

```
class Itinerary < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :itinerary
  has_many :activities
end
```

Activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Here is where I'm starting with activities_controller.rb. FYI, my current_user.id is created by an authenticated_system.rb, so don't worry about that part.

```
def destroy
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  if @itinerary.user_id == current_user.id

    @activity.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to("/") }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

I tried to connect the models using a has_many :through approach, but I didn't know how to do it for more than three models, and I wasn't sure that was the right approach anyway. Thanks again for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
if @activity.location.itinerary.user_id == current_user.id
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks, Ismael. Can you tell me the name for this approach of stringing together the different models? I'm a noob, but I'd like to learn more (and will google to find some good resources based on your response.)

Comment: You can do this tanks to the relations you set up with belongs_to and has_many which set those methods to you. You can find information about it ate the guides

Answer (score 0):

You really only need to ask the activity for its location, then ask the location for its itinerary, than ask it for its user. It's a bit of a violation of the Law of Demeter, but it will work.

```
loc = @activity.location
itin = loc.itinerary
if itin.user_id = current_user.id
...
```

That should work.

Comment: Austin, I really appreciate your response. I went with the other answer just because it was a simpler approach, but thank you for your time.